# SASS responsive grid mixin

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I have a mixin for building responsive grid system in SCSS:

```
@mixin grid($cols, $marg) {
    margin: 0 $marg $marg 0;
    width: ( (100% - (($cols - 1) * $marg )) / $cols );

    &:nth-child(#{$cols}n){
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
// $cols - number of columns
// $marg - gutter
```

I took it from [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS9QgrG2oXo).

But it works correct only with **first** media query (in my case with screen width 480 to 768px). When **second** media query fires, previous grid elements don't override 'margin-right: 0'.

See [DEMO](http://codepen.io/VladDev/pen/QGJMdj)

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: What do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. Instead of using only min-width:

```
@media screen and(min-width: 480px){
  li{ @include grid(2, 2%); }
}
@media screen and(min-width: 768px){
  li{ @include grid(3, 2%); }
}
@media screen and(min-width: 920px){
  li{ @include grid(4, 2%); }
}
```

We just need to write both min-width and max-width in our media queries.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  li{ @include grid(2, 2%); }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 919px){
  li{ @include grid(3, 2%); }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 920px){
  li{ @include grid(4, 2%); }
}
```

see [DEMO](http://codepen.io/VladDev/pen/xRQpRp)